# Medical exam for student visa in Sweden

Tags: visas, health, sweden, student-visas, cyprus

I'm currently visiting Sweden, and I need to undergo a medical exam to finalize my application for a student visa for Cyprus (namely, the  needed checkups are tests for tuberculosis, hepatitis B, C, syphilis and HIV / AIDS), because I'm not an EU citizen. I've contacted a few medical centres in Sweden, and it appears that they don't do medical exams. I've also contacted some private medical centres, but to no avail so far either.

Does this mean that I have to look outside of Sweden for a thing as simple as a general medical exam mentioned above? Such would involve additional expenses, time and effort, to travel elsewhere and then come back to Sweden.

I'm from Canada, so travelling to Canada and back just to do a medical exam doesn't seem quite plausible for me. What options do I have at my disposal?

Comment: Were the medical centres you contacted the public ones? Most private clinics should offer medical certificate services (for a fee of course).

Comment: Also, I claim no knowledge on Cyprus, but a cursory internet search tells me the medical exam is only required after arrival?

Comment: General regular check-ups as practised in North America are unknown in many European countries (not only Sweden). You are not expected to see a general practitioner unless you have a specific complaint or perhaps for targeted screening based on age and family antecedents. 
A potential solution would be to ask the Cyprus authorities if they have specific requirements or a description of that exam. For example, is this about specific infectious diseases or do they have a checklist you could give to a doctor? This has worked for me for exams required for sport competitions or activities.

Comment: @xngtng Both before and after arrival.

Comment: @Relaxed There used to be a yearly regular checkup option in Canada before (at least in Ontario), but since about 2018 or so there is no longer such an option. And here the matter is about a pre-visa checkup, not a regular one.

Comment: The consulate may have a list of clinics that offer the services. In any case, private clinics that do medical exams for e.g. professional driving licenses should be able to do it for visas as well.

Comment: @sequence That was clear, the reason I mentioned this is some background on why “a checkup” or “medical exam” not linked to a specific complaint might be a completely foreign notion to the people you talked to. They don't routinely do it, it doesn't fit in their regular billing system, or might even create concerns about liability. On the other hand, if you can present them with more specific requirements or find some analogy with something that's common like sports or, indeed, driving licenses, you might have better luck.

Comment: @xngtng Thanks for the hint. It's not easy at all to find a private medical clinic in Sweden, at least by internet search in English. Maybe I'll try in Swedish.

Comment: @Relaxed I said to them directly that I need it for a visa. One clinic gave me a contact of a clinic that does this type of checkups for Australia, there is one (in Denmark though!) that does checkups for visas to Canada. But when I mentioned Cyprus, I was told "no idea".

Comment: It could be useful to add all this to the question. As it stands, it sounds as if you couldn't find a place to do any kind of medical checkup and you seemed surprised that something “as simple as” a general medical exam wasn't common.

Comment: As I understand it now, the issue is how to meet the requirements for Cyprus specifically. It's not so surprising most clinics wouldn't know them, it's a small country. Hence the idea of getting more detailed requirements (what disease to screen for, which organ/systems need to be checked, e.g. cardiovascular system, vision, etc.) A doctor should be able to work off such a list, especially if they are already doing it for other purposes. I realise it's not a full answer obviously, that's why I post it as a comment (and upvoted the question) but it seems worth trying.

Comment: @Relaxed I have updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.medicinskaintyg.se/en/tjanster/lakarintyg-utomlands/ offers  certificates for staying abroad. They seem very knowledgeable about the problem with different requirements for different countries. From their site:

> Exactly what should be investigated varies on a case-by-case basis and very often there is a special form to be filled out, signed and stamped.

> We make sure to have regular contact with each country's embassy, to sort out any question marks before you leave